# TFS 2012 add member disabled under group membership

Tags: tfs, member, membership

I am using TFS 2012 Server Administration Console to manage group memberships for different team projects. However, it seems that after recent updates (TFS Update 1 / numerous Windows updates) I am unable to add members under any group. This might be unrelated but I have not done any other modifications to the system.

[image: Disabled 'Add member' section]

The whole add member section is disabled and I have no idea why. I have always used this functionality logged in with the same Windows administrator account.

OS is Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

There are some security related issues with TFSUpdate1. Please see the [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2803625?wa=wsignin1.0) and [apply the patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36392)

Comment: Thank you for the links, but apparently this patch did not solve the issue.

Theoretically I should have all the permissions. Anyway as a workaround, I can manage members through the TFS web client from the same account. This works fine.

Comment: It behaves the same way in Update 2 as well. I haven't really looked into it since and been using the web interface for managing user settings.